# Juniper Netconnect error on Mac Failed to gain root privileges

Tags: juniper-network-connect

I am getting the below error on Juniper Netconnect VPN connection

```
A software error caused the tunneling service to terminate. See the Log Viewer for more information.
```

Just above this in the log i see

```
7 ncproxyd[p1575.t771] ncproxyd.error Failed to gain root privileges: Operation not permitted (ncproxyd.cpp:302)
2016-04-29 10:12:44.657 ncproxyd[p1575.t771] ncproxyd.info ncproxyd exiting status 1 (ncproxyd.cpp:103)
```

I think it is related to latest Java update. Do you have any idea what permissions might have gone wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also saw this after fixing a broken Homebrew installation.  I may have been a little too enthusiastic with my `/usr/local` permission resetting.  As noted below a reinstallation fixed things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that installation owner was not correct.

`/usr/local/juniper`

This should be owned by `root`

I reinstalled the netconnect and that fixed all the owner ship

To download the netconnect , you can get from  `<Your_RNA_URL>/dana-cached/nc/NetworkConnect.dmg`